# css absolute positioning with right alignment

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
     img
     {
         position:absolute;
         right:50px;
     }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
     <h1>This is a heading</h1>
     <img src="logocss.gif" width="95" height="84" />
</body>
</html>
```

from http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_right

If I change the style of h1 to:
    h1
         {
             position:absolute;
             right:50px;
         }
then both the h1 and img overlaps.

Now I didn't mention the top position for img or h1. So in the first case when h1 didn't have any style, the img left h1 alone and occupy the next available space after the h1 and was aligned to the right side (50 px apart). But when I mentioned h1 to be 50px apart (with absolute positioning), both the img and h1 overlapped. Now as I didn't mention the top position then why is not img leaving h1 alone and follow it (instead of overlapping it)? I understand that we are using absolute positioning which leaves top position ambiguously specified so why is it automatically assuming that the img has to occupy the top:0 position? If h1 occupies top:0 position then it is fine because it is the first element. But img should respect the space of h1.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: So you want the h1 and the image to be stacked vertically?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because `position:absolute` removes the element from the flow of the document - they don't stack anymore because they are position absolutely.

I think a better way to do this would be:

```
h1, img{
    float:right;
    margin-right:50px;
    clear:both;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R7bXZ/

**Even better way for you:**

Just give the h1 `text-align:right;`.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KvMLb/2/

Answer (score 6):

yeah, you could also just change the `top` tag in the css like so:

```
 img
 {
     position:absolute;
     right:50px;
     top:100px;
 }
 h1
 {
     position:absolute;
     right:50px;
     top:75px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `img` is occupying the `top: 0` position is because, by specifying `h1` as `position: absolute`, you're taking it out of the page flow. `img` attempts to calculate it's position and doesn't see the `h1` there. There's not a great way around this using only `position: absolute` although [this JSFiddle might work for you](http://jsfiddle.net/bwkrm).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any document for this? I would like to know more about this.

Comment: This article (http://www.digital-web.com/articles/web_design_101_positioning/) has a good explanation of how `position: absolute;` works.

Answer (score 0):

Read here on absolute positioning: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning

When using absolute positioning, the element you apply it to, in lamens terms, becomes disconnected from the page and teh rest of the elements.  It is essentially making that element behave on its own with 0 influence from other.  From what I have read you want position:absolute img to detect where the h1 is and avoid it.  This is simply not possible using position:absolute, it is in itself designed to NOT do that.

How do you want these to actually appear so I can assist in achieving that without using position: absolute?

Comment: I was just trying to understand the behavior only. Thanks for the answer.